# Can a server join a GetInstant room in order to get notified of changes?

Tags: goinstant

Can a server join a room in order to get notified of changes?

Usecase:  A user updates a field A, for which another calculated field B must be updated. However only the server is able (has the rules) to calculate the field B based on A.

What I mean would be the following flow:

1. user updates field A.
2. gets synced to GetInstant
3. GetInstant notifies all users in the room among which the server, of the changed field A
4. Server calculates field B
5. field B gets synced to GetInstant
6. (optional: clients get notified of updates of field B)

As a workaround I could let all updates go through by own server and do the plumbing myself, but I'd rather not. Moreover, directing traffic like this is costly for the sporadic case that I need to do these calculated field transforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you can't join a room via the rest api and register for notifications server-side.  This is on the roadmap, however.  Currently your options to do this serverside are limited to polling.